# Install Ubuntu as VHD alongside Windows 8, Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-8

I have Windows 7 as my primary OS, and I have also installed Windows 8 on a VHD and I am able to boot from that VHD as well, so in my boot menu I get options for both Windows 7 and Windows 8. 
Now I want to install Ubuntu on a VHD and want it to appear as option on boot screen.
Is that possible, if yes, how?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

VHD virtualization is only available for Windows 7 and 8. You can't use it with Ubuntu. However, you could install Ubuntu inside your windows 7 (WUBI) ,this will give you option for Ubuntu along with Windows. Also, in this method, Ubuntu is actually installed in a virtual disk file, though not a vhd file.

Comment: WUBI is no longer  supported, nor recommended. I think this answer needs to be updated :)